# Paste datas field by field in an Access table

Tags: database, ms-access, data-binding

**Situation :**

I have an Access table, *table X*, with about 30 fields, 200 records each.

I worked a lot on it, applied highly restricted validation rules for nearly each of those fields and after that I created a Datasheet Form which is bound to it so that the user can enter new datas in the proper format.

The issue is that the datas of *table X* aren't up to date anymore. They come from an Excel Worksheet which is really disorganized and wouldn't respect the validation rules I set if I could magically copy past them into my *table X*.

What I need to do is :

1. Import the new datas in an other Access table, *table Y*, so that I can adapt MANUALLY the datas which don't respect the validation rules I set in *table X*
2. Then, **this is where I need HELP**, find the easiest way to copy paste the well-organized datas from *table Y* into *table X*, because for the moment the best solution I have is to do it manually...

So, my **Question :**

Is it possible to copy field by field the datas from *table Y* into *table X* ?

Any other suggestions are welcomed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If the order of fields matches that of the columns, it is a simple copy-n-paste.

Comment: Haha if it is that simple I am ashamed. I will try, but I thought that because of all thos rules, combo/list boxes with multiple values it wouldn't be that easy. I will let you knwo if this works

Comment: Yes, it works, just had some issues with the primary key for some reasons...but globally, it works thanks !

Comment: It does work - given that a paste is possible, of course.

Comment: well I don't manage to do it on fields with combo/list box allowed to contain multiple values. I copy, I paste, but the cells remain empty.

Comment: Yes. If it works with comboboxes, it will copy/paste the bound value, which often is different from the displayed value.